# Boolean not updated before onPostExecute runs

Tags: android, android-asynctask, socket.io-java-client

I have a problem with returning the result value to `onPostExecute()` of an `onBackground()` function in the Async Class of Android.

What I want to do is to search for a specified contact name in a database using socket.io and then when I find it; `return` `true` to `onPostExecute` so that I can do something there when the contact has been found. If nothing has been found, `false` shall be returned and something else should be done in `onPostExecute()`. 
I set the `boolean` global value "success" to `true` or `false` respectively and try to pass this value to `onPostExecute()`, but for some reason the value is assigned AFTER `onPostExecute()` is called ... must have something to do with asynchronous operation, but since I am not an expert, I hope someone can give me some hint on how to do it right so that the `boolean` value is updated, BEFORE `onPostExecute()` checks the value.

This is my code:

```
public class AsynchronicTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Boolean> {

SocketIO socket = null;
AsyncObject asyncObject = null;
Boolean success = false;

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(final Object... argument) {
    this.asyncObject = (AsyncObject) argument[0];

    try {
        System.out.println("Trying to connect to: "
                + asyncObject.getURL());
        socket = new SocketIO(asyncObject.getURL());
        socket.connect(new IOCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                JSONObject queriedUsername = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    queriedUsername.put("Username", asyncObject.getQueryInput());
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                socket.emit("clientRequestSearchUsername", queriedUsername);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void on(final String message, IOAcknowledge argIO,
                    final Object ... arg) {
                if (message.equals(asyncObject.getServerMessage())) {
                    if (arg[0].equals("null")) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", "No Result Found");
                        success = false;
                    } else {
                        success = true;
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "RESULT OK!");
                    }
                };
            }
        });

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("error", "Wrong Server URL");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return success;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", result.toString());

    // Give reply when username query has finished
     if (result.equals(true)){
     Log.d("DEBUG", "Contact found, adding to contactlist");
     // Populate data in contactViewAdapter
     asyncObject.getContactListAdapter().populateAdapter(asyncObject.getQueryInput());
     Toast.makeText(asyncObject.getContext(), "Contact added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } 
     else { 
         Log.d("DEBUG", "No Success adding contact, no contact found");
         Toast.makeText(asyncObject.getContext(), "Username not existent, no contact added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
     }  
 }
 }
```

Comment: You're starting another thread (by virtue of calling socket.connect) from your AsyncTask background thread.  You can't expect to return something from the second thread and have it magically synced up with your AsyncTask background thread.

Comment: tru to make your boolean varibale static so that there wont any copy of this varibale in many threads..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `doInBackground(...)` returns value before method `on` of `new IOCallback()` is called. SocketIO establishes the connection in its background thread that's why it need some time for this action. Your solution: don't use AsyncTask. Just create something like this:

```
void yourMethod (AsyncObject asyncObject, YourListener listener) {
    System.out.println("Trying to connect to: " + asyncObject.getURL());
    socket = new SocketIO(asyncObject.getURL());
    socket.connect(new IOCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onConnect() {
            JSONObject queriedUsername = new JSONObject();
            try {
                queriedUsername.put("Username", asyncObject.getQueryInput());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            socket.emit("clientRequestSearchUsername", queriedUsername);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnect() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(SocketIOException arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(JSONObject arg0, IOAcknowledge arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void on(final String message, IOAcknowledge argIO,
                final Object ... arg) {
            if (message.equals(asyncObject.getServerMessage())) {
                boolean success;
                if (arg[0].equals("null")) {
                    Log.e("ERROR", "No Result Found");
                    success = false;
                } else {
                    success = true;
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "RESULT OK!");
                }
                listener.ready(success);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code of `YourListener`:

```
public interface YourListener {

    public void ready(boolean value);
}
```

And just call this method in your class:

```
yourMethod(asyncObject, new YourListener() {
    @Override
    public void ready(boolean value) {
            // copy here your code from onPostExecute
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me out! I see that I still need some practice in understanding how all this threading is working, good to have some experts around